# ways to generate jar file from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Wanted to check , what produces a jar file from pom.xml with no plugins included?  Let say I a class file

```
my-app/
|-- src/
    |-- main/
        |-- java/
            |-- com/
                |-- example/
                    |-- MyClass.java
|-- pom.xml
```

```
Myclass.java
package com.example;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Maven!");
    }
}
```

```
pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
    <finalName>model</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

should the above pom.xml without plugins produce a jar file ?

Comment: If you run the proper goals yes it will produce a jar.

Comment: well i wonder, if you already have the files, why not just try it out?

Comment: @GyroGearless  I am using a buildpacks for java to produce the jar file with my minimalistic content of pom.xml. This is to test that buildpack works. It does not produce the jar file when I checked the container.  With my limited knowledge on maven workflows, I was testing with very minimal contents in pom.xml file. It produces a proper jar file  when i have a shade plugin <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>. So I was wondering, if user can try to produce jar file any other ways?

Comment: This is not your main problem. You even know the answer by testing it. You should post a new question about the original problem you are trying to resolve with the details for reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `Packaging` section of `Introduction to the lifecycle` [in the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#packaging), you can see that it will execute `jar:jar` (the `jar` goal of the `maven-jar-plugin`) in the `package` phase by default.

You can also see this in [the `Usage` section of the `maven-jar-plugin` documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html).

> Usually there is no need to mentioned the 'maven-jar-plugin' explicit cause it's bound to the Maven Build Life Cycle.

This is assuming you are using the `jar` packaging which is the default. In your example, you even set this explicitely with `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your `pom.xml`.

The `jar` goal of the `maven-jar-plugin` will create a JAR from your compiled project sources and resources. However, it won't contain any dependencies.